# Wordpress storefront Sticky header with centered menu and logo

Tags: css, wordpress, storefront

I'm working on wordpress project for a friend. Unluckily (for me), she decided that site need sticky header which goes beyond my actual CSS understanding. I've created css that helps me center logo and menu below. Now I need help with making it sticky and setting logo in between menu/navbar positions.

Screen of header
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg3PF.jpg

`````
a:focus {
 outline: 0; 
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&family=Playfair+Display+SC&display=swap');

/* center logo*/
.site-branding{
width:100% !important;
text-align:center;

}
.site-header .site-branding img {
margin: auto;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
max-width: 300px;

}
/* center menu */
nav#site-navigation {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom:55px;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: Playfair Display SC;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.woocommerce-active .site-header .site-header-cart {
width: 21.7391304348%;
margin: 0 auto;
float:none;
}
.entry-content{
        font-family: Open Sans;
    }
    .h2 {
        font-family: Playfair Display SC;
    }````
`````

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***sticky and position : fixed*** for [sticky items](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp).

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Can you guide me how to implement this rn ?

Comment: of course. Can you tell me what will stick on the screen?

Comment: After convo with my friend, she decided that she want big header as it is rn  (Screen of current header i.gyazo.com/f0f4cf4f958f7ee22d0b5826b21fe193.jpg) but after clicking in menu positions it will need auto scroll down after loading this subpage. Can you help me with that?